# Modified gem files on rubymine to checkin on github

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, rspec, rubygems, rubymine

I have some gem files on rubymine in my external libraries which I am modifying as per my project requirements. Eg: I am modifying the `HtmlPrinter` class located under `RSpec::Core::Formatters` and when I execute rspec formatter I am able to see the changes. I want to checkin those changes in my github repo.

Is it possible or no because the file is in external libraries? What do I need to do if I have to make changes to some existing gem and then checkin it along with my project on github?

Answer (score 1):

Best method would be to clone the original repo on Github and add your changes there. Commit your local changes to your fork on Github and, in your Gemfile, use the `:git` argument(?) like so:

```
# Gemfile

gem 'rspec', :git => 'git://github.com/yourname/rspec.git'
```

This way,

1. You'll keep a clean copy of the repo with your additions on github and away from your application.
2. You may choose to keep your fork updated with the upstream (original Rspec repo) or not.

Rubymine will install the gem by fetching the gem from the git repo and this shouldn't cause any problems since the latest versions of the application internally [use bundler to manage gems](http://blog.jetbrains.com/ruby/2011/07/bundler-is-the-official-gems-environment-provider-in-rubymine/).